# PHP operator precedence & string concatination?

Tags: php

See the following code snippet

```
$i=1;

echo $i.($i++);
```

in a quick, I thought the result would be `12` but the actual result is `21`.

also

```
echo $i,$i++;
```

I thought it would be `12` but its `11` .

```
echo ($i = ($i++)); //result is 1

echo ($i = ($i+1)); //result is 2
```

But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First example

Code in brackets is evaluated first - in this case `($i++)`. The value of `$i` is taken (1) and then the     variable is incremented to 2. So you then have this, where `$i` is 2.

```
echo $i . '1'
```

From this, the value of `$i` is substituted in, and you get `'2' . '1'`, which is concatenated to give `'21'`.

#### Second example

It's easier to rewrite this to clear up the `,` separator. The line `echo $i, $i++;` is equivalent to:

```
echo $i;
echo $i++;
```

The first line obviously outputs `1`, and the second will output that same value, then increment `$i` (`++` is the [post-increment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)). If you were to put another `echo $i;` at the end, it would output `2`.

Comment: You said the code in brackets evaluates first. then `echo ($i = ($i++));` will be 2 instead of 1. or am i missing something ?

Comment: In that code, you're taking the value of `$i`, incrementing it, then assigning the old value back - hence why the original value is outputted.

Comment: looks like im in trouble. I am thinking it like this, while checking the code the innerbracket `($i++)` which need to be evaluated to 2 (1+1) and then it assign that value to local $i and at last it will echo the result as 2. also see my updated question :(

Comment: `$i++` is not equivalent to `$i + 1`. The value of `$i++` is `$i`, but the value of `$i` is incremented afterwards. Perhaps you're thinking of `++$i`?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My brain got hijacked :)

Answer (score 3):

When a variable is not involved into any arithmetic operation (like your first `$i`), PHP will not create a temporary variable.
Thus, your first `$i` will be evaluated at the end of the statement, when `$i++` has already been executed.

To prevent this, you can still write:

```
echo ($i += 0).($i++);
```

But this is obviously not a good coding practice.

**EDIT**: When you use `,` it is actually syntactic sugar to shorten two PHP statements. It is strictly equivalent to:

```
echo $i;
echo $i++;
```

Since incrementation is executed after the last statement, `11` is indeed the result.

Answer (score 1):

As per the PHP documentation stated at: [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

**First Case**

```
$i=1;

echo $i.($i++);
```

`$i` is initialized to value 1. Now, `++` follows a higer precedence than `.` and it has right-associative. This means your `$i++` will be evaluated first. In this case , the value of `$i++` will be `1` and the next value of `$i` will get incremented to `2`. hence `$i` is 2

Now `.` has the next precendence after `++`, which is left-associative. hence it will evaluate values starting from left.

so `$i`=2 and `$i++ =1`, hence the output 21

**Second Case**

```
$i=1;

echo $i,$i++;
```

Here, there is only one operator `++`. Hence the need for comparision of precedence doesn't arise. Hence, it will be evalauted by default standard of left-associative. `$i = 1`, `$i++ = 1`. Hence `11`

**Third Case**

```
echo ($i = ($i++)); //result is 1
```

In this case, now `=` is an assignment operator and is right-associative, so `$i++ = 1`. And since it is an assignment operator value of `$i++` will be stored in `$i`. hence  `echo ($i = 1);` which will result in output being `1`.

**Fourth Case**

```
echo ($i = ($i+1)); //result is 2
```

Again, this will be right-associative, so `$i+1 = 2`. hence  `echo ($i = 2);` which will result in output being `2`.

Comment: This one really helped me to understand, However i already accepted one answer (im feeling that SO is bad in this case) :(

Answer (score 0):

Firstly for the second place it uses $i eq 1
Then it increases it to 2;
So for the first place it uses 2 and for the second - 1

Comment: What if there no Parentheses ?

Comment: @Red the result will be the same

Comment: @Red I know, but now it's not without the answer